# Can't connect to Amazon AWS EC2 with Hansoft Client

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to connect to my Hansoft server on my AWS server that is running Windows Server.

I've tried opening all inbound traffic to test, but that hasn't worked. I'm able to ping the server so it's there.

Hansoft servers use default port 50256.

What else could I try?

***Launch-wizard-1*** security group settings below.

**Inbound Security rules:**

- All Traffic, All protocols, All port range, Source 0.0.0.0/0
- RDP, TCP Protocol, Port range 3389, Source 0.0.0.0/0
- All ICMP, All protocols, Port range N/A, Source 0.0.0.0/0

**Outbound Security rules:**

- All Traffic, All protocols, All port range, Source 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Can you paste your security group rules

Comment: Sure, just updated. I have 2 security groups. 1 is default, 2 is the launch-wizard-1

Comment: Add new security rule TCP Port 50256 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: @error2007s Something else is wrong. His rule "All Traffic, All protocols, All port range, Source 0.0.0.0/0 " means its wide open.

Comment: Are you sure its running? While logged into the instance, can you 'telnet localhost 50256' and get a connection? Have you tested it locally and confirms it works?

Comment: @RodrigoM His rule All Traffic, All protocols, All port range, Source 0.0.0.0/0 RDP is for RDP and not TCP he needs to open the port 50256 for TCP

Comment: @error2007s Sorry to disagree but "all traffic all protocols all ports" is just that. His RDP and ICMP rules are redundant.  As is the suggested addition unfortunately.   There is no  problem with the SG.  Try it. Remove rules #2 and #3. You will still be able to ping and rdp.

Comment: I can connect using the Hansoft client installed on the server. I'm using "localhost" as the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

Are you sure 100% the service is running?

While logged into the instance, can you 'telnet localhost 50256' and get a connection? Have you tested it locally and confirms it works?

Disable your local firewall and anti-virus.

Have you checked the local Windows Firewall on that server?  That will block you in some configurations, so you need to check that. You may need a new inbound rule there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried telnet. It just gives me a blank command prompt after I enter that command in.

Comment: @john Did you try adding this rule TCP Port 50256 0.0.0.0/0 and then try ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I tried that one but no luck: Custom TCP Rule, TCP, 50256, 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: @john - Great Re telnet yet that sounds like a good connection. As I have commented, it is not the SG.  Try everything else I suggested.  I suspect the Windows Firewall.

Comment: Also try the telnet remotely.  Does is connect?

Comment: I missed the firewall step. Setting the port to open on in/out connections worked. Thank you @RodrigoM!